# How to handle AJAX exception in ASP.NET Core MVC and show custom error page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-5

I have just begun to work with ASP.NET Core MVC and web development in general, and I am struggling to understand how to show an error page from an AJAX call.

What I would like to do is to show a custom page with the error message on if the Ajax call fails. So far I have the following code which takes me to my 500 page when I throw an exception in the controller but how do I get it to show the exceptions message on that page?

`StartUp.cs` middleware:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Error", "?Code={0}");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

Error controller:

```
    public IActionResult Error(int? Code = null)
    {
        if (Code.HasValue)
        {
            if (Code.Value == 404 || Code.Value == 500)
            {
                var viewName = Code.ToString();
                return View(viewName);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

AJAX call:

```
// Use ajax call to post to the controller with the data
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Renewals/GenerateQuotes",
        data: { selectedContractIds: ids },
        success: function (response) {
                     // Show success and refresh the page
                     Toast.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: 'Quotes Generated'
                            }).then(function () {
                                location.reload();
                            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               // Response message
               var response = xhr.responseText;
               window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Error", "Error")?Code=' + xhr.status;
        }
})
```

Comment: usually we show error for ajax request in a small part of the page, e.g : a <div> ..., or via a popup tooltip at some corner of the screen ... Why do you want a whole error page? If you want some rich HTML predefined custom error page embedded in the current page, you can return that partial HTML as the response to the ajax request so that it can be shown. That response can be obtained via `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought it would be useful to see the error its for an internal app. I will take a look at this option.